# Unable to open Windows Disk partitions in solaris 11

Tags: solaris, ntfs

Not sure if I have come to the right place with the right problem but I don't really have much option as I have not found even a close solution to my problems in any other website during my tireless search times in the internet. So, here it goes-------

I have recently installed solaris 11. The main problem I am facing at the moment is that the NTFS windows HD partitions are not appearing in solaris file system, which was not the case when I used ubuntu. Every single file on my HD was exposed to me when I was in ubuntu.

I installed something called ntfs -g drive but I think I am not using it correctly as most of the time I am copying and pasting commands because I do not have sufficient knowledge to write them myself.

Any assistance in this matter?

** Yeah I am talking about the exact same ntfs -3g. But how can I see the windows HD partitions in solaris?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mounting NTFS in Solaris 11**

1. Grab these two files: [FSWpart.tar.gz](http://aminsblog.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/fswpart-tar-gz-remove.png) and [FSWfsmisc.tar.gz](http://aminsblog.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/fswfsmisc-tar-gz-remove.png)
2. Rename files:

   ```
   # mv  fswpart-tar-gz-remove.png FSWpart.tar.gz 
   # mv  fswfsmisc-tar-gz-remove.png FSWfsmisc.tar.gz
   ```
3. Install the packages.

   ```
   # tar -zxvf FSWpart.tar.gz 
   # tar -zxvf FSWfsmisc.tar.gz 
   # pkgadd -d . FSWpart 
   # pkgadd -d . FSWfsmisc
   ```

   Select "y" if prompted for conflict in files:

   ```
   The following files are already installed on the system and are being used by another package: 
       * /etc/gnome-vfs-2.0 <attribute change only> 
       * /etc/gnome-vfs-2.0/modules <attribute change only> 
       * /usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0 <attribute change only> 
       * /usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0/modules <attribute change only> 
       * /usr/sbin/mkntfs * /usr/sbin/ntfsclone 
       * /usr/sbin/ntfscp 
       * /usr/sbin/ntfslabel 
       * /usr/sbin/ntfsresize 
       * /usr/sbin/ntfsundelete 
       * - conflict with a file which does not belong to any package. 
       Do you want to install these conflicting files [y,n,?,q] y
   ```
4. Find the target partition

   ```
   # iostat -En
   ```
5. Mount partitions in the devices into folders you like:

   ```
   # mkdir /mnt/d 
   # mount -F ntfs /dev/dsk/c5t0d0p3 /mnt/d
   ```
6. Add mount targets to /etc/vfstab

   ```
   /dev/dsk/c5t0d0p2 - /mnt/c ntfs - yes - 
   /dev/dsk/c5t0d0p3 - /mnt/d ntfs - yes -
   ```

[Source](http://aminsblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/mount-ntfs-in-solaris-11/)

Answer (score 1):

Linux is going to give you better options and probably support and stability for accessing a NTFS filesystem since the user base would be more likely to want to access a NTFS filesystem.

I haven't tried opening a NTFS filesystem under Solaris 11 yet to copy it over to ZFS, but I'd reco trying to install and use the vendor supplied pkgs over the ones mentioned by Maverick.

Let's see what's in the repos:

`pkg search ntfs
INDEX                       ACTION VALUE                                                                   PACKAGE
pkg.description             set    Utilities which provide access to and manipulation of NTFS file systems pkg:/system/file-system/ntfsprogs@2.0.0-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
pkg.summary                 set    ntfsprogs NTFS utilities                                                pkg:/system/file-system/ntfsprogs@2.0.0-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
com.oracle.info.description set    NTFS utilities                                                          pkg:/system/file-system/ntfsprogs@2.0.0-0.175.3.0.0.30.0`

Get pkg info for the discovered pkg:

`pkg info -r /system/file-system/ntfsprogs
             Name: system/file-system/ntfsprogs
          Summary: ntfsprogs NTFS utilities
      Description: Utilities which provide access to and manipulation of NTFS
                   file systems
         Category: System/Administration and Configuration
            State: Not installed
        Publisher: solaris
          Version: 2.0.0
    Build Release: 5.11
           Branch: 0.175.3.0.0.30.0
   Packaging Date: August 21, 2015 03:51:43 PM
             Size: 1.03 MB
             FMRI: pkg://solaris/system/file-system/ntfsprogs@2.0.0,5.11-0.175.3.0.0.30.0:20150821T155143Z`

Look at what files come w/the pkg:
`pkg contents -r /system/file-system/ntfsprogs
...
<file & dir listing>
...`

Pkg install dry run (fails on SPARC):
`pkg install -n /system/file-system/ntfsprogs
pkg install: The following pattern(s) only matched packages that are not available for the current image's architecture, zone type, and/or other variant`

You also may want to install/use rmvolmgr to make mounting the devices easier.